# Pass Data from React to node express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass the generalDetail  data from my react front end to my node server. I am currently getting a connection refused error.

(OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/home net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

here is my onSubmitForm function:

```
  onSubmitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  let data = {
            generalDetail: this.state.generalDetails,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            middleName: this.state.middleName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName
      };

      axios.post("http://localhost:5000/home", data).then(() => {

       }).catch(() => {
          console.log("Something went wrong. Plase try again later");
      });


}
  //end

  onContentChange(fieldname, data){

    console.log('On Content Change', data);

     this.setState({
       [fieldname]: data

    });
  }



}
```

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


// http://localhost:5000/api/home

app.post('/api/home', (req, res) => {
  const data = [
    {req.body.generalDetail},
  ];

  res.json(data);
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: you are declaring your api route as '/api/home' but sending the data to '/home'. You need to make sure you are sending data to the correct route.

Comment: if you change your .catch to handle the error you will see that you are getting a 404. try using: .catch( (error) => { console.log(error); ));

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000 //your port number

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

Comment: so did you see "Server running on port ${port}" in you console

Comment: No I didn't actually haha

Comment: No it isn't unfortunately

Comment: did u start the server. "node server.js" file  . Did u get any errors?

Comment: its saying invalid syntax for 

    {req.body.generalDetail},

Would you happen to know the correct syntax? I'm trying to pass the data through from react to the backend.

Comment: update this in your code `const data = req.body.generalDetail`

Comment: @TomHunt did u suceed ?

Comment: hmm getting closer it just says "text" on the console

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code into this

Example

```
onSubmitForm = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = {
              generalDetail: this.state.generalDetails,
              firstName: this.state.firstName,
              middleName: this.state.middleName,
              lastName: this.state.lastName
        };

        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/home", data).then(() => {
           //do something
         }).catch(() => {
            console.log("Something went wrong. Plase try again later");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cors preflight code in your backend code (server.js).

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
app.post('/api/home', (req, res) => {
  const data = [{ generalDetails: req.body.generalDetail }];
  res.json(data);
});
```